# Sync data between instances using binary data

Tags: sql-server, text, synchronization, varbinary

I sporadically sync data from a small set of tables in production. I cannot access the production machine directly, so historically

- I submit "select * from dbo.source",
- DBA copies from Citrix, pastes locally the result as tab-delimited.txt
- I import tab-delimited.txt into Excel
- I use Excel formulas to concat an INSERT / UPDATE script, one per record
- I run the result on DEV / QA

As long and tedious as that looks, it skips the most arduous step - escaping all the ' or control characters to avoid syntax errors.

I remember, once upon a decade or two ago, that one could `select cast(Column as varbinary(255)) as Column`, then INSERT / UPDATE the **binary** version of the data and SQL Server would automagically convert to the underlying datatype. However, for the life of me, I cannot locate any of the tutorials I once used.

Is this still the most convenient way to sync data when I MUST convert the table to text for transport? If there's something better, what is it? If it's still a decent approach, can anybody remember the name this approach was given so I can seek out a refresher tutorial?

Comment: Why are you using Excel when you can just import the data directly into SQL Server using bulkload and process it as a set?

Comment: Good question! When I sync a table, I do so across multiple instances, sometimes checking the script into source control. I suppose we could check in the tab-delimited.txt, but I suspect I'll be asked for the script as that's more easily consumed by our auditor(s).

Comment: Why not have a dedicated DB for importing the data into on a "master" instance and then log-ship it to other instances, each instance can have the same t-sql script to process a staging table from this database into the target database(s)

Comment: `bcp.exe` can bulk load, it's just a single command. Or you can use `SqlBulkCopy` from either C# or PowerShell. Messing around with Excel is the worse way to do this, it does funny things with fields that look like numbers or dates.

Comment: @Stu we have a day-old backup from Production, which relatively locked down. Only one member of our team has access via Citrix. They have to run queries, then copy the results into local clipboard before pasting into a text editor and dropping into a shared folder. Log-shipping is a *great* idea, but not something I can implement. I have freedom in the scripts I send over.

Comment: @Charlieface yes, Excel is a problem, hence the desire to use binary values. I have access to execute programs against DEV and QA environments, but not two other pre-production layers, so a script-based solution is what I'm after.

Comment: I don't understand: what *do* you have access to? Bulk Copy just needs `bulkadmin` role